# Accidentally typed sudo chmod 666 /dev/*

Tags: permissions

I accidentally typed `sudo chmod 666 /dev/*`
instead of sudo `chmod 666 /dev/ttyACM0`
for giving port permission.

After that everything became blank except the background
I restarted the computer and it says `low graphics`

How do I reset it?

Comment: You could try booting in recovery mode and correcting the permissions.  Whether that will work for you across a subsequent reboot I don't know.  To try this, reboot, select "Advanced options for Ubuntu", "Ubuntu (recovery mode)", "root".  Then `cd /dev; ls -l | more` to see the permissions.  Then for each file or directory that's lost the "x" permission (which is likely to be all the directories) replace it with `chmod +x block` etc.

Comment: @JeffreyRoss most of the `/dev` files should not be executable. Here's my system as a reference `stat -c '%n %a' /dev/* | pastebinit`:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/24259644/

Comment: at least recover executable bit on all subdirectories in `/dev/` by [`chmod -R a+X /dev/`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39761/execute-bit-on-directories-but-not-files)

Comment: Did you resolve this somehow?

Comment: Besides running `sudo chmod 666 /dev/*` what else did you do? Did you make changes before it? Can you explain the context in which you wanted to run `chmod 666 /dev/ttyACM0`? Had you installed or uninstalled drivers, video or otherwise? Had a kernel update been installed since the last reboot? Does selecting an older kernel in the GRUB menu (hold down Shift if it doesn't appear) make the "low graphics" problem go away or otherwise produce a noticeable change? Was anything significant, such as upgrading/installing packages, happening when you ran the command or rebooted? How did you reboot?

Answer (score 2):

If you're on a modern kernel using the [`udev` (`devtmpfs`) filesystem](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/77936/222377), just **reboot**.  The `/dev` nodes in such systems are populated by the kernel and will be reinitialized with the proper permissions at boot.

You can tell if this is the case for your system with `mount | grep 'on /dev'`:

```
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,relatime,...,mode=755)
```

Unless your Ubuntu is very old (2012? 2013?), or you've specifically reconfigured your system to use static device nodes, rebooting should fix you right up.

Comment: OP said they restarted and got `low graphics mode`...

Comment: I think this may, in effect, be the answer. That is, the permissions changes in `/dev` [probably weren't](https://askubuntu.com/questions/897316/accidentally-typed-sudo-chmod-666-dev#comment1512193_897316) the cause of the problem. (And certainly "How do I reset it?" if interpreted to mean those permissions, is fully answered here.) There's an argument to be made that the question should be closed as unclear but I'd rather keep it open (unless it's a duplicate of something) and consider this the answer. I believe that will help others who find this question and answer by searching.